# EXTERNAL TABLE to a file in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is it possible to use file in `LOCATION` for external table in HIVE?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table1 
(
  line string
)
LOCATION '/hdp_in/fd/file.txt.gz';
```

cause I get an error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException Parent path is not a directory: /hdp_in/fd/file.txt.gz file.txt.gz
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.mkdirs(FSDirectory.java:1957)
(...)
```

Do I have to use only directories? I haven't found that info in Manual Reference...

Regards 
Pawel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you will have to put this file in a directory and then create an external table on top of it. As per the documentation : **An EXTERNAL table points to any HDFS location for its storage, rather than being stored in a folder specified by the configuration property hive.metastore.warehouse.dir**

Even if you create an internal table hive by default creates a directory for it inside the **hive.metastore.warehouse.dir** and the same behavior is expected while creating an external table except for the fact that the default directory is not used.